# Backup pluggable database

Tags: oracle

I have a pluggable database and I want to backup.Now,I did this in windows:

```
set ORACLE_SID=ORE(My pdb name)
echo ORACLE_SID

rman target /
```

But,I ran into these errors:

RMAN-06171(Not connected to target database)

Can anyone please advice what my target db should be? I want to backup my pdb and not container db.

Answer (score 1):

You should connect to the container database in order to perform backups. After that you can run

```
BACKUP PLUGGABLE DATABASE pdb_name;
```

Refer to the official documentation:
[Backing Up PDBs with RMAN](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/BRADV/rcmbckba.htm#BRADV735)

Also, your connection does not work, because there is no database instance with name of the pluggable database - only the container instance is running and pdbs are stored in it.

Answer (score 0):

Restoration and Recovery of PDB (Pluggable database), we need to ensure that valid rman backup available.

SQL>restore pluggable database PDBORCL1;

refer the useful post: -

https://readmeout.com/restore-and-recover-pluggable-database-pdb-from-rman-backup/